# All COM add-ins hidden after closing last Excel Window

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

Following an update of Office 365 in March or April 2022, my COM Add-ins for Excel started to disappear:

- Restart your computer, run Excel and choose new blank workbook: all COM add-ins show as expected. Then close the workbook and any other Excel windows.
- Relaunch Excel and all COM add-ins have disappeared: the UI in the Ribbon tabs do not appear, as if the Add-ins were not loaded. Yet, the add-ins show as being loaded in the COM Add-ins manager window.

2 workarounds identified:

- Go to the COM add-ins manager, untick+OK and retick+OK the COM add-ins. They will re-appear in the Ribbon tabs.
- Close Excel, open the Task Manager. Realize that **Excel is still running**, and kill the process (End Task). Start Excel again and the add-ins will show in the Ribbon tabs.

How can I avoid relying on these workarounds to use my add-ins comfortably?
This does not seem to be a problem with specific COM Add-ins but rather a new behavior from Excel. I believe so because the behavior is the same for all COM Add-ins, including add-ins preinstalled by Microsoft such as 'Microsoft Power Pivot for Excel' or 'Microsoft Data Streamer for Excel'. There is no such problem with Ms Word for example.

I have Windows 10 and Excel 365 version 2204 Build 15128.20178 click to run.

Comment: Are the Add Ins showing on the Main Menu above the Ribbon? That is where my Adobe and QuickBooks COM add ins show up.

Comment: This is the point, they show but disappear if closing all windows and then re-opening Excel (which I understand keeps running in the background). The Adobe PDF Add-In does also show the same bug behavior as other Ms or Vendor add-ins.

Comment: I am not seeing that here (multiple systems) and all up to date now or also in the past.  I don't know why for you but I will look around a bit.

Comment: I just bought a new PC this week and was able to reproduce the bug on a clean Windows 10 and Office install. I reproduced the bug by activating the 'Microsoft Data Streamer for Excel', without installing any other Add-In (this one came packaged with Office). Same bug on two other computers, including a version running on Win7.

Comment: Are you running the build I mentioned? I just checked the build on the Win7 machine: 2002 Build 12527.22121. So could it be due to a Security update then?

Comment: I'm using the same version number of Office as yours. I didn't get this problem with com add-ins. Did the third-part add-ins or build in add-ins? You can try to repair Office application.

Answer (score 0):

Timebro, a software dedicated to tracking the activity of a desktop, seems to be interfering when loading Excel. Deactivating the tracker before opening the Excel file resolves the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).